# Only show one of each type of sensor sql issue

Tags: sql

I use the following query:

```
select 
     t.`SENSOR`, 
     t.`OPENED`, 
     t.`STATUS`
from 
     SENSOR_STATUS t
inner join 
(
    select 
          `SENSOR`, 
           max(`ID`) as MaxID
    from 
        SENSOR_STATUS 
    group by 
        `SENSOR`
) tm on t.`SENSOR` = tm.`SENSOR` and 
        t.`ID` = tm.MaxID
```

But get duplicate results. I tried adding distinct, but it still shows duplicate results:

```
Cabinet Door 2020-04-09 16:32:49 Closed
Closet Door 2020-04-07 18:37:18 Closed
Garage Main Door 2020-04-09 16:44:40 Closed
House Back Door 2020-04-09 18:01:12 Closed
House Front Door 2020-04-08 15:35:00  Closed
House Side Door 2020-04-09 13:50:22 Closed
Kitchen Sink Window 2020-04-06 17:24:16 Closed
Kitchen Window 2020-04-06 17:24:05 Closed
Cabinet Door 2020-04-09 16:32:49 Closed
Closet Door 2020-04-09 16:33:02 Open_Alerted
Fridge/Freezer Door 2020-04-08 16:49:01 Open_Alerted
Garage Main Door 2020-04-09 16:44:39 Closed
House Back Door 2020-04-09 18:01:12 Closed
House Front Door 2020-04-08 15:35:00 Closed
House Side Door 2020-04-09 13:50:20 Closed
Kitchen Sink Window 2020-04-06 17:24:16 Closed
Kitchen Window 2020-04-06 17:24:05 Closed
MainRoom 2020-04-08 17:43:55 Light
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want the max id of each location of the sensor and the value of that max ids status. Each time a sensor triggers, it adds a new record to the table.

Comment: It would appear you have duplicate `ID` values in your table.

Comment: ID Primary int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Well that should prevent that then. Can you share some sample data which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/gM7FZEuXz8NYsXEY8

Comment: From that it would appear that you have multiple entries at the same time for the same sensor. You should probably add a unique index over (sensor, opened, status) to prevent that happening. Or perhaps increase the precision of your timestamp column to include microseconds.